# How to view CAS using 4 different type system descriptor xml files

Tags: java, nlp, uima

I am trying to view content of CAS using CAS Viewer (http://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.1.0-incubating/docs/html/tutorials_and_users_guides/tutorials_and_users_guides.html#ugr.tug.cpe.configurator_and_viewer)

It works perfectly fine for the CAS which is created using single type system descriptor XML. But, I am not sure how to view CAS which is created using multiple type system descriptor XML.

I also have corresponding type system packages/classes generated too in classpath, but don't know how to use that.

Alternately, I tried to use Eclipse CAS viewer (UIMA Plugin). That too needed single Type System Descriptor XML.

Let me know is something is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very experienced with UIMA, but I think you could create a new TypeSystem that [imports](http://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.2.2-incubating/docs/html/references/references.html#ugr.ref.xml.component_descriptor.type_system.imports) all the types required from other TypeSystem descriptions.